# how to return to anchor after post

Tags: php, javascript

I have an application that creates quotations, orders etc. and as the user adds items the page reloads and can quite long. The problem is then the user has to scroll down to the last item to add another one - this gets to be quite time-consuming. Is there a way I can get it to do this automatically? I have tried putting anchors on each line item like this;

```
echo "<form action='display_quotation.php' method='post'>\n";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='quote_id' value='$quote_id'>\n";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='item' value='$detail_number'>\n";
echo "<a name='item_$detail_number'></a>\n";
```

and put the javascript ;

```
echo "
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
<style type='text/css'> table {font: 13px arial} </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function goToAnchor() {
    window.location.hash='item_$item';
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload='goToAnchor();'>\n";
```

This doesn't seem to work - I get in the URL  http://my_domain/display_quotation.php?#item_3 but the page always goes to item 2 no matter what item is passed via post.

Comment: Which browser? Are you sure it always goes to item 2 or does it perhaps remain at the top?

Comment: I've tried in both FF and Chrome and its the same - not at the top, a couple items down.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

`window.location.hash='item_$item';`

to

`window.location.hash='item_<?php echo $item; ?>';`

Comment: TY Vishnu, however I wasn't clear. I have edited the OP to reflect that the variable $item was passed in post and inserted in script tag.

Comment: So, once your page is loaded, you check the source code in Browser, and make sure that the contents of <script> is same as you intended.

Comment: Yes, the script is loading correctly - as is indicated in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple idea that I have is, instead of page-loading and doing scripting to go to the hash, you can choose to do like this:

```
<?php header("location : yourpagename.php#$item"); ?>
```

Another solution is using jQuery, to scroll down to the bottom of the page.

A nice example is here using jQuery: http://djpate.com/2009/10/07/animated-scroll-to-anchorid-function-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the browser scrolls to the right anchor, but then the location of the anchor in the page shifts due to a reflow due to styles/images etc. kicking in a bit later. Try going to the same anchor again, after a bit of delay. Do this in your `load` event handler:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    with (document.location) hash && (hash = hash);
}, 1);
```

Play around with a larger delay if 1ms doesn't cut it.

Comment: I'm not really clear on this - could you tell me exactly what to put in the script tag? Should it be exactly as above?

Comment: Yes, the above is a generic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

heres the very simple solution

```
<?php

if($POST)
{
    $iItemId = $POST['item_id'];
    //after saving the item to cart redirect to
    redirect('domain.com/#'.$iItemId);
}

?>

<a id="1">Product 1</a>
<a id="2">Product 2</a>
<a id="3">Product 3</a>
```

Comment: I have tried using `code`<form action='display_quotation.php?#item_$detail_number' method='post'> and it produces the same result.

Comment: does your product items has this attributes "id=$item_id" 
ex: <a href="" id="">...</a>

Comment: It turns out I didn't have the html right:-( I failed to put some text in the anchor tag <a id="1"></a> and so the page wouldn't scroll down to it. See above in my OP. Thanks all who tried to help.